# Why does the debugger in KDB sometimes not show in 'interactive' mode?

Tags: kdb

I've got a function where I'm throwing a deliberate error to pause execution and enter interactive debug.

I have set `\e 1`.

When the KDB REPL encounters it, it pauses execution as expected, but the debugger doesn't actually appear. When I finally enter `\`, it prints the debugger output, like it was printing to an invisible terminal, but then drops to the normal namespace.

What am I doing wrong?

**Video of the problem:**

https://www.loom.com/share/db9ee83e7d8e4fb7bb6b454b49ec9cdc

Comment: Your environment: does the `[developer]` in your session indicate you are using [KX Developer](https://code.kx.com/developer/)? That might vary the handling of errors. If so you, might get advice from the Developer team by posting the question at [community.kx.com](https://community.kx.com/).

Comment: Do you get the same effect if you use [Signal](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/signal/) to throw an error?

Comment: @SJT I indeed using KX Developer, and it does appear to have been the cause of the issue. I'm not sure why exactly, but disabling it seems to have fixed things, for now. Thanks for suggesting it!